# Cannot build for ios in NET Maui "ibtool exited with code 1"?

Tags: ios, xaml, maui, visual-studio-mac

I'm having issues with NET Maui where I'm trying to display a Map in iOS. I have inherited the map in a custom class to add some helper methods. I can build and run fine with android device and emulator but when building for ios device or maccatalyst I get 3 build errors:

Error: /usr/bin/xcrun exited with code 1
Error: ibtool exited with code 1
Error: Interface Builder can’t determine the type of “CustomMap.cs”. This may be due to a missing SDK.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;

public class CustomMap : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map
{ ... }
```

Comment: Did it work well if consume a 'blank' CustomMap (with no code in it)?